# Problem with Javascript, AJAX & JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm an iPhone Developer whose quite new to web development so please forgive me if I'm making silly mistakes here:

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the user selects an item from a drop-down, it calls some javascript, which sets off an AJAX request to a PHP file I have which returns some JSON. - That JSON includes a thumbnail image filename, and a caption for the image. These need to be passed in to an image, and textfield respectively in my document.

The problem is, it fails after trying to eval the json. - The same happens with `eval(json);` and `JSON.parse(json);` I worked this out by calling document.write('something'); periodically in my response method. - It will always be able to write up to the point where it parses the json.

I am sure my PHP is valid and my request is good (I can output the response from the JS fine).

Here is the function I call when a new item is selected in the drop-down:

```
function changeImage(id){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
        var responseObject = eval(res);
        var caption = responseObject.caption;
        var textField = document.getElementById('caption');
        textField.value = caption;
        var imagePreview = document.getElementById('imgPreview');
        imagePreview.src = responseObject.filename;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getCaption.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When I output res (or access the php file manually) the JSON looks like this:

```
{"caption":"A caption","filename":"myimage_thumb.jpg"}
```

why is the JSON eval failing?

**UPDATE:**
This error is logged: `SyntaxError: Parse error`

Comment: What does "fails" mean? Does a Javascript error occurr, does the browser crash, does an error message pop up...

Comment: 'Something like this' - perhaps you might want to pass the complete output to http://www.jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @Codo - see updated question (sorry should have checked the console)

Comment: If it's a parse error you really ought to post the complete output so that it's possible to see where the error is.

Comment: @pimvdb - that is complete output, and just checked - it's valid

Comment: is it something wrong with this line: var responseObject = eval(res); ?

Comment: Could you try `eval("(" + res + ")")`? That makes it work for me using `eval`, though `JSON.parse` with your output works just fine.

Comment: @pimvdb - that works - post it as answer and I will accept/vote up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're taking a JSON string and pretending that it's a Javascript object literal. But, remember, *JSON is merely **named after** Javascript's object notation!*

You're then hoping that `eval` will directly evaluate this and return an object, but this is not the case.

---

#### Observations

Writing the following in the Firebug console:

```
eval('{"caption":"A caption","filename":"myimage_thumb.jpg"}')
```

will also yield a SyntaxError. (Ideally, you'd have narrowed your problem down to this!)

Interestingly, constructing an object more explicitly does work (for this input):

```
eval('new Object({"caption":"A caption","filename":"myimage_thumb.jpg"})')
```

As does just forcing the input into being a certain kind of expression, with parentheses:

```
eval('({"caption":"A caption","filename":"myimage_thumb.jpg"})')
```

---

#### Explanation

It all comes down to this statement from 12.4 in the ECMAScript standard:

> Note that an `ExpressionStatement` cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a Block.

[This article](http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/why-wont-eval-eval-my-json-or-json-object-object-literal/) explains the issue in depth, but in summary **the solution is to use `JSON.parse(res)` to obtain an object from a JSON string**. This is the proper approach, and it will not fail as long as your input is valid JSON.

Comment: A nice explanation Tomalak! +1 :-)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Thanks! It just takes a bit of research.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the eval-line against:

```
eval('var responseObject = ' + res);
```

Comment: Or: `var responseObject = eval('(' + res + ')');`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of suggestions that I would give in this context

- Can you try doing a `console.log(res)` or `alert(res)`, so that you know you really *have* a `res` before you try using it.
- Never use `eval(res)`. Why not use `JSON.parse(res)` (on modern browsers, since you have IE5 browsers too up there), or even better `$.parseJSON` (if using jQuery)
- If you are sending if from PHP, use `json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS)` to prevent syntax errors while parsing. Check my answer (link below) in another thread.

  [How to store a php array on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561348/how-to-store-a-php-array-on-the-client-side/5561387#5561387)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
eval("(" + res + ")");
```

so that it wraps it in `(...)`. I'm not sure why yet.

Anyway, you could also look into jQuery, because then it's as simple as:

```
$.getJSON("path", function(json) {
    // json is the ready-to-use object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use eval -

```
var rsltObj = eval('(' + jsonStr + ')');
```